# NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains for getting path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to write a NSArray into a file. This is the code I used

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GraphData.txt"];
```

[myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

I cannot locate this path where the file is meant to be saved, so Trying to retrieve this file using this piece of code returns NUll

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GraphData.txt"];    
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"FROM FILE::: %@ FROM FILE::", myArray);
```

I figured I need to create a file first before writing into it, but I don't know where. I can give a manual path for eg. my desktop or documents folder and write the array to the file, but I guess it wont work when I'll try to deploy it into the real app. So, help please

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should check to see if you successfully wrote out your array via:

```
BOOL success = [myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
if(success == NO)
{
   NSLog( @"did not write file to %@", filePath );
}
```

Keep in mind that the array will only write out if the contents of the array are all property list objects (e.g. "`NSString`", "`NSData`", "`NSArray`" or "`NSDictionary`" objects), otherwise you'll get a "`NO`" sent back via the "`success`" BOOL.

Comment: I used this check and the BOOL variable returned YES.

Comment: And the bottom NSLog line, the one that has "`FROM FILE:::`" in it, what happens when you try to print out "`[myArray description]`"?

Comment: Let's try one more thing. ***Before*** you write out the array into the file, can you print out the contents of the array?  How many objects/entries are there?

Comment: My array is an array of NSDictionary that has 58 entries, with each entry containing a nested NSdictionary of variable length (2-5). Yes I can print out this array file, I was also able to write this array when I gave path=@"/Users/Home/Documents/Projectname/Graph.txt"; I created a Graph.txt file manually in this case